Gradle Build Failing with "The supplied phased action failed with an exception"
I'm encountering an issue while building my Flutter application. The error message I'm receiving is:
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
Failed to run Gradle Worker Daemon.
Process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 5' finished with non-zero exit value 1.


Steps I've Taken:
Java Version Check: I ensured that I am using a compatible version of Java (Java 11). I ran java -version and confirmed that it was indeed Java 11.
Gradle Daemon Cleanup: I tried stopping the Gradle daemon using gradle --stop, followed by cleaning the project with flutter clean and flutter pub get.
Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin Update: I updated my android/build.gradle to use the latest Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin versions:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20'
    }
}


In gradle-wrapper.properties, I set:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip


Project Cleanup and Rebuild: After making these changes, I ran flutter clean, flutter pub get, and attempted to run the app again.
Verbose Output: I also tried building with more detailed output using ./gradlew build --stacktrace to gather more insights into the error.
Checked Running Processes: I verified if there were any lingering Gradle or Java processes in the background and terminated them if found.
IDE Restart: I restarted my IDE (both Android Studio and VS Code) to ensure that all settings were refreshed.
Project Directory: As a last resort, I moved my project to a different directory to rule out any directory-related issues.
Despite all these efforts, the problem persists. Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Could you please run this command and share what the logs say ?
This command
./gradlew build --stacktrace --info --debug
